# What is best way to reduce circular dependancy in following pseudo code

Tags: design-patterns, software-design

I typically end off design my software architecture as follows, which is  a dead end.

```
import ExtraWorld,SuperWorld;

class World{

 constructor(){
     let a = new ExtraWorld()
     let b = new SuperWorld()
 }
}
----
class SuperWorld extends World{
}

class ExtraWorld extends World{
}
```

More reallife example

```
class BasicBlock{
 // Basic block can internally contain ifblock, forblock
}

class IfBlock extends BasicBlock{
}
class ForBlock extends BasicBlock{
}
```

How I can redesign the architecture and rename so that it makes much sense

Comment: Why would a superclass need variables of derived types? What would an Animal do with a Bear and a Cow in its constructor?

Comment: Why would the World constructor need instances of its subclasses? You need to give more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: The question remains the same after your edit. Why does a base class contain references to derived classes? It shouldn't need to.

Comment: It seems I was trying to generalise es6 circular dependency problem. Got most satisfying answer with https://esdiscuss.org/topic/how-to-solve-this-basic-es6-module-circular-dependency-problem#content-39

Comment: The question could be clearer, but maybe are you looking for [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)? Or for  [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)?